# How to fix the Server returned HTTP response code 400 and tranisitions cannot be processed

Tags: java, rest, jira

I'm trying to proceed the JIRA transitions by java coding, most of the time it works, but the jira rest api call sometimes return the below error: (Actually with this error, the transition is processed)

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://testingSite/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/ABC-123/transitions
```

Also, there are some case the rest api call do not return errors but the transition is not proceed.

Here is my coding, most of the time it works, so it ruined my days to figure out what is happening.

```
try {
    String authkey = "YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=";
    URL url = new URL("http://testingSite/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/ABC-123/transitions");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authkey);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    String data = "{\"transition\": {\"id\": \"71\"}}";
    os.write(data.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    os.close();

    content = connection.getInputStream();
    in = new InputStreamReader(content);
    br = new BufferedReader(in);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error comes from this line:

```
content = connection.getInputStream();
```

I expect there is not exception and all transition is processed but the behaviour is quite strange for me.

Behaviour 1 : Server returned HTTP response code : 400 but the transition is processed

Behaviour 2 : Server do not return any error but the transition is not processed

Comment: A 400 is a _"Bad Request"_ so what changes in your requests between when it works and when it doesn't?

Comment: FYI, HTTP Basic Authorization typically encodes the credentials string as base64, so instead of `"admin:password"`, `"YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ="`

Comment: @Phil I didn't change anything

Comment: If nothing changes and sometimes it works / sometimes it doesn't, I'd raise a support ticket with Atlassian.

Comment: @Phil Wrong coding above, the credentials is base64 instead of `"admin:password"`. I think I will raise a support ticket with Atlassian because this problem need me to manually login the account and process a few transition per week.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about _"wrong coding"_ but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication ~ _"...where credentials is the **base64 encoding** of id and password joined by a colon"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was looking for reference documentation [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/6.2.7/#d2e1289). And its stated that

> POST: 400 - If there is no transition specified.

You have you transition id hardcoded and maybe for that type of issue it has different transition id or something similar. Try to call

```
GET /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions?{transitionId}
```

to verify you transition is actually there.

Comment: Okay, I will try to use `api/2/` instead of `api/latest`. I am very sure that the issue type is correct because this function is called after obtaining approval.

I think i can try to use 
`URL url = new URL("http://testingSite/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/ABC-123/transitions?71");`

Comment: Yes, you can try it out and then come back with results. FYI, I'm not a specialist in JIRA API, it's just something that I found in ref doc.